# Secrecy of Firebase Cloud Messaging Server Key

Tags: android, security, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a smart home app that communicates with the smart home system on the local network (or via VPN). I would like to integrate with Firebase Cloud Messaging and would need a server. It's a free app that I don't make any money off, so I don't want to have a server to maintain and keep an eye on.

I'm thinking that the I could make the server available open-source on GitHub. I want the setup of the server to be as easy as doing a clone and running a single command. That leads me to the question: **Can I leave my server key for the project in a public repos for others to use or what kind of abuse would that open for?**

I see they (naturally) tell you to keep the server key a secret at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#role , but I'm wondering if  that would be the case for me when it's okay for others to have their own instance of the server on their LAN where their own devices registers.

Comment: put the keys in OS environment variables, never in source code

Comment: Yeah, that is the general rule. But I'm asking about this particular case because I want to distribute the server software without the end user having to set up a key themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server-key allows to send notifications to the applications registered for the sender-id associated to the key.
Because of this you should keep your server-key private.

In your case you can ask each user to register its own Firebase Project.
Then each user can have its own `sender-id` and `server-key`  (listed in the settings page).

On the server you can pass the server-key as a command line paramenter.
On the client you need to ask the user to type its own sender-id, then you can register for that sender-id using the API:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken("sender-id-2", "FCM")
```

Comment: Note that `messaging.getToken()` usually returns `[messaging/unknown] - cannot connect to the network` if user device is using a VPN.